# installing python xlwings module

Tags: python, pip, conda, xlwings

I am trying to get the xlwings module working in python. I installed it yesterday, but have the following problem:
When I update the package, it confirms that my version is the latest version, 0.24, but when I run xlwings commands, it says that the version is 0.17.1, which is about one and a half years old. This means the tutorial material won't run.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and updating with the commands

```
pip install xlwings --upgrade
```

and

```
conda upgrade xlwings
```

I am then very confused. How come the version I have downloaded yesterday is the latest version, but the version I am running is over a year old?

`pip3 show xlwings` gives

```
PS C:\Users\Ethan-tuna> pip3 show xlwings
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Name: xlwings
Version: 0.24.0
Summary: Make Excel fly: Interact with Excel from Python and vice versa.
Home-page: https://www.xlwings.org
Author: Zoomer Analytics LLC
Author-email: felix.zumstein@zoomeranalytics.com
License: BSD 3-clause
Location: c:\users\ethan-tuna\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages
Requires: pywin32
Required-by:
```

Comment: What is the result of `pip3 show xlwings`?

Comment: question edited. it says 0.24 is installed

Comment: Try installing from the git repository (`git clone https://repo && cd repo && pip3 install .`) and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: you can't install from GitHub as a C++ dll and the VBA component need to be built.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python on your computer ? (one in appdata\roaming\python and another one installed with conda)

Comment: that might be the case, as both update commands work. (But I also updated them both to be the latest version). What is the difference between the two?