# Unable to update "httplib2" module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to run a script called **quickstart.py** on Linux. However, I get this error at line 39:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart.py", line 39, in main
    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)
  File "/home/balance/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/balance/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 321, in build
    discovery_http.close()
AttributeError: 'Http' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I did a bit of reasurching, and it seams like the issue is related to the **httplib2** module ([Link here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1047)). However, updating the module using pip and pip3 doesn't work. I tried a variety of things, but none of them work. It won't update past version **0.14.0**, even though the current version, according to **pip_search** since pip search is broken, is **0.20.4** The things I tried are:

pip3 install httplib2

```
Requirement already satisfied: httplib2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.14.0)
```

pip3 install httplib2==0.20.4

```
Collecting httplib2==0.20.4
  Using cached httplib2-0.20.4-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.3,<4,>=2.4.2; python_version > "3.0" in /home/balance/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from httplib2==0.20.4) (3.0.7)
Installing collected packages: httplib2
Successfully installed httplib2-0.20.4
```

When I checked httplib2's version, it was still 0.14.0

I also did sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade, but that didn't do anything.

When checking Stackoverflow, the only other question is one with no answers ([Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68134845/installing-python-xlwings-module)). Can somebody please tell me why I can't update this module?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you aren't using virtualenv or any other python environment manager?

Comment: And that your user has write permissions to that Python site packages directory? (A frequent issue on other OSes with Python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the wait @Nick Bailey, I am doing this in school. (Without giving to many details, I don't know you, my parents and my teacher let me do my own thing) I am not using a python environment manager, but it does not appear that I have write permissions. Also, when trying to uninstall httplib2 with **pip3 uninstall httplib2** with and without sudo, it does this

`Found existing installation: httplib2 0.14.0
Not uninstalling httplib2 at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'httplib2'. No files were found to uninstall.`